# Keep getting Unable to update: com.google.appengine.tools.admin.RemoteIOException

Tags: java, google-app-engine

All of a sudden I've started getting today the below exception and GAE project update is STUCK... tried transaction rollback but it didn't help...

Any advice?

```
Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.RemoteIOException: Error writing to server
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.RemoteIOException.from(RemoteIOException.java:29)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.RemoteIOException.from(RemoteIOException.java:24)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:1180)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload$UploadBatcher.addToBatch(AppVersionUpload.java:1551)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.uploadFile(AppVersionUpload.java:882)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.uploadFiles(AppVersionUpload.java:256)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.uploadFilesTransaction(AppVersionUpload.java:224)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:200)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:572)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:58)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction.execute(AppCfg.java:1537)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:360)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:222)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:127)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:123)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1676)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1672)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1245)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:326)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:289)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:244)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.LoggingClientDeploySender.send(LoggingClientDeploySender.java:33)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:1178)
    ... 12 more
...
```

Many Thanks

Comment: I'm using Python not Java, but I have been having some intermittent problems with deploying my app today. I got at least 3 different errors. I was able to get through every now and then by retrying over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was found to be a communication problems in the local network which caused GAE deploy to keep failing...

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem is actually java 12. I was using adoptopenjdk12 on mac and had to remove that to be using java 8 instead.